# Java establish connection to jdbc with code

Tags: java, database, jdbc, connection

Hello I am struggeling to establish an automatic connection to my jdbc database. When ever I run the program it gives me this error: `java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException:java.net.ConnectException:Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.`

When I manually connect to my jdbc driver the program works fine. I would like to know if there is a way that I can connect to the driver using code instead of doing it mannualy.

Here is some of my code:

```
 String createDB = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/C:/211092207/HotelBookings;create=true";
        String createCustomer = "CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER ( CUSTOMERID NUMERIC(15) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, LASTNAME VARCHAR(20), FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(20), GENDER CHAR(1), EMAIL VARCHAR(50), CREDITRATING VARCHAR(9), NATIONALITY VARCHAR(20), DATEOFBIRTH VARCHAR(20), PHONE NUMERIC(10), CELLPHONE NUMERIC(10) )";
        String createRoom = "CREATE TABLE ROOM ( ROOMNO NUMERIC(5) PRIMARY KEY, ROOMTYPE VARCHAR(9), DAILYRATE NUMERIC(20), STATUS CHAR(1))";
        String createBooking = "CREATE TABLE BOOKING (BOOKINGID NUMERIC(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, ROOMNO NUMERIC(5), PROPOSEDCHECKINDATE DATE, PROPOSEDCHECKOUTDATE DATE, CHECKEDIN CHAR(1), ACTUALCHECKINDATE DATE, CHECKEDOUT CHAR(1), ACTUALCHECKOUTDATE DATE, CANCELLED CHAR(1), CANCELDATE DATE, CANCELREASON VARCHAR(100),AMOUNT NUMERIC(20), PAYDATE DATE, PAYMODE VARCHAR(15), STATUS VARCHAR(50), PAID CHAR(1), DATE DATE, CUSTOMERID NUMERIC(15))";
        String refOne = "ALTER TABLE BOOKING ADD FOREIGN KEY(CUSTOMERID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CUSTOMERID)";
        String refTwo = "ALTER TABLE BOOKING ADD FOREIGN KEY(BOOKINGID) REFERENCES BOOKING(BOOKINGID)";

        Date one = new Date(20/9/2014);
        Date two = new Date(10/10/1010);
        Date three = new Date(16/9/2014);
        Booking book = new Booking();
        book.SetBookingID("9879974564");
        book.SetRoomNumber("001");
        book.SetProposedCheckInDate(one);
        book.SetProposedCheckOutDate(one);
        book.SetCheckedIn('F');
        book.SetActualCheckInDate(one);
        book.SetActualCheckOutDate(one);
        book.setCancelled('F');
        book.SetCancelDate(two);
        book.SetCancelReason("");
        book.SetAmount(10.20);
        book.SetPayDate(one);
        book.SetPayMode("Bank Deposit");
        book.SetStatus("Done");
        book.SetPaid('T');
        book.SetDate(three);
        book.SetCustomerID("9112315190086");

        String insertStatement = ("INSERT INTO ROOM(ROOMNO, ROOMTYPE, DAILYRATE, STATUS) VALUES (001, 'Single', 120.00, 'A')");
        String insertStatementTwo = ("INSERT INTO ROOM(ROOMNO, ROOMTYPE, DAILYRATE, STATUS) VALUES (002, 'Single', 120.00, 'A')");
        String insertStatementThree = ("INSERT INTO ROOM(ROOMNO, ROOMTYPE, DAILYRATE, STATUS) VALUES (003, 'Double', 230.00, 'A')");

        String insertStatementFour = ("INSERT INTO CUSTOMER(CUSTOMERID, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, GENDER, EMAIL, CREDITRATING, NATIONALITY, DATEOFBIRTH, PHONE, CELLPHONE) " +
                "VALUES (9112415190086, 'Nel', 'Piet', 'M', 'pietnel@hotmail.com', 'Good', 'America', '31/12/2014', 0721360363, 0721589859)");

        String insertStatementFive = ("INSERT INTO CUSTOMER(CUSTOMERID, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, GENDER, EMAIL, CREDITRATING, NATIONALITY, DATEOFBIRTH, PHONE, CELLPHONE) " +
                "VALUES (9112315190086, 'van Tonder', 'Hannes', 'M', 'hannesvantonder@gmail.com', 'Good', 'South Africa', '31/12/2014', 0711360193, 0791589789)");

        String insertStatementSix = ("INSERT INTO CUSTOMER(CUSTOMERID, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, GENDER, EMAIL, CREDITRATING, NATIONALITY, DATEOFBIRTH, PHONE, CELLPHONE) " +
                "VALUES (9115987489968, 'le Roux', 'Paul', 'M', 'paul@gmail.com', 'Good', 'South Africa', '31/12/2014', 0721361193, 0821589789)");
try
{
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(createDB);
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

}
catch(Exception ex)
{

}
conn.close();
```

I suspect that maby I would have to add another statement in my try block.
When I debug my program the problem lies at this statement:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(createDB);
```

when the program should execute that statement it goes to the catch and throw the error message.

Comment: Please post the error message..

Comment: Looks like your db serve is not running. or runs on another port.

Comment: Tou need to give username and password 

String createDB = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/C:/211092207/HotelBookings;create=true";

something like (user=USERNAME;password=PASSWORD;)

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates "Connection Refused". Reduce code test to just connecting until that is successful.
The username and password are not apparently set anywhere so start with that. See Derby examples of connect string and options for where to set the user and pw. Recommend not hard coding password but rather send it in via connection parameter, taken from operator as console argument.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow 7 steps in JDBC,

1)Load the driver

2)Define the Connection URL

3)Establish the Connection

4)Create a Statement Object

5)Execute a Query

6)Process the results

7)close the Connection

you are not loading the class anywhere.
For derby database my guess is

```
   Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
```

Moreover  you have just created the statement,  you need to write your required query and then execute it too. remember to close.