# JDBC Establish connection to database

Tags: java, jdbc, connection

Hello I am having problems with starting up my database.  Can you please point out to me where my problem lies, thanx in advance.

The error message that I get: **java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException:java.net.ConnectException:Error** **Connecting** **to** **server** **localhost** **on =** **port**  **1527** **with** **message** **Connection** **refused:** **connect.**

Here is my code:

```
public void CreateDatabase()
    { 

    String createDB = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/C:/211092207/HotelBookings;create=true";
    String createCustomer = "CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER ( CUSTOMERID NUMERIC(15) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, LASTNAME VARCHAR(20), FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(20), GENDER CHAR(1), EMAIL VARCHAR(50), CREDITRATING VARCHAR(9), NATIONALITY VARCHAR(20), DATEOFBIRTH VARCHAR(20), PHONE NUMERIC(10), CELLPHONE NUMERIC(10) )";
    String createRoom = "CREATE TABLE ROOM ( ROOMNO NUMERIC(5) PRIMARY KEY, ROOMTYPE VARCHAR(9), DAILYRATE NUMERIC(20), STATUS CHAR(1))";
    String createBooking = "CREATE TABLE BOOKING (BOOKINGID NUMERIC(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, ROOMNO NUMERIC(5), PROPOSEDCHECKINDATE DATE, PROPOSEDCHECKOUTDATE DATE, CHECKEDIN CHAR(1), ACTUALCHECKINDATE DATE, CHECKEDOUT CHAR(1), ACTUALCHECKOUTDATE DATE, CANCELLED CHAR(1), CANCELDATE DATE, CANCELREASON VARCHAR(100),AMOUNT NUMERIC(20), PAYDATE DATE, PAYMODE VARCHAR(15), STATUS VARCHAR(50), PAID CHAR(1), DATE DATE, CUSTOMERID NUMERIC(15))";
    String refOne = "ALTER TABLE BOOKING ADD FOREIGN KEY(CUSTOMERID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CUSTOMERID)";
    String refTwo = "ALTER TABLE BOOKING ADD FOREIGN KEY(BOOKINGID) REFERENCES BOOKING(BOOKINGID)";

    Date one = new Date(20/9/2014);
    Date two = new Date(10/10/1010);
    Date three = new Date(16/9/2014);
    Booking book = new Booking();
    book.SetBookingID("9879974564");
    book.SetRoomNumber("001");
    book.SetProposedCheckInDate(one);
    book.SetProposedCheckOutDate(one);
    book.SetCheckedIn('F');
    book.SetActualCheckInDate(one);
    book.SetActualCheckOutDate(one);
    book.setCancelled('F');
    book.SetCancelDate(two);
    book.SetCancelReason("");
    book.SetAmount(10.20);
    book.SetPayDate(one);
    book.SetPayMode("Bank Deposit");
    book.SetStatus("Done");
    book.SetPaid('T');
    book.SetDate(three);
    book.SetCustomerID("9112315190086");

    String insertStatement = ("INSERT INTO ROOM(ROOMNO, ROOMTYPE, DAILYRATE, STATUS) VALUES (001, 'Single', 120.00, 'A')");
    String insertStatementTwo = ("INSERT INTO ROOM(ROOMNO, ROOMTYPE, DAILYRATE, STATUS) VALUES (002, 'Single', 120.00, 'A')");
    String insertStatementThree = ("INSERT INTO ROOM(ROOMNO, ROOMTYPE, DAILYRATE, STATUS) VALUES (003, 'Double', 230.00, 'A')");

    String insertStatementFour = ("INSERT INTO CUSTOMER(CUSTOMERID, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, GENDER, EMAIL, CREDITRATING, NATIONALITY, DATEOFBIRTH, PHONE, CELLPHONE) " +
            "VALUES (9112415190086, 'Nel', 'Piet', 'M', 'pietnel@hotmail.com', 'Good', 'America', '31/12/2014', 0721360363, 0721589859)");

    String insertStatementFive = ("INSERT INTO CUSTOMER(CUSTOMERID, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, GENDER, EMAIL, CREDITRATING, NATIONALITY, DATEOFBIRTH, PHONE, CELLPHONE) " +
            "VALUES (9112315190086, 'van Tonder', 'Hannes', 'M', 'hannesvantonder@gmail.com', 'Good', 'South Africa', '31/12/2014', 0711360193, 0791589789)");

    String insertStatementSix = ("INSERT INTO CUSTOMER(CUSTOMERID, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, GENDER, EMAIL, CREDITRATING, NATIONALITY, DATEOFBIRTH, PHONE, CELLPHONE) " +
            "VALUES (9115987489968, 'le Roux', 'Paul', 'M', 'paul@gmail.com', 'Good', 'South Africa', '31/12/2014', 0721361193, 0821589789)");

    try
    {  
        try {

            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "not working");
        }
```

When I debug my code the next statement makes the compiler go to the catch statement that throws an error

```
 Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(createDB);

        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        try
        {
        //Driver = new Driver();
        //java.sql.Driver(createDB);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
        try
        {
            stmt.executeUpdate(createCustomer);
        } //End try
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        } //End catch
        try
        {
            stmt.executeUpdate(createRoom);
        } //End try
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        } //End try
        try
        {
            stmt.executeUpdate(createBooking);
        } //End try
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        } //Catch
        try
        {
            stmt.executeUpdate(refOne);
        } //End try
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Failed");
        } //End catch

        try
        {
            stmt.executeUpdate(refTwo);
        } //End try
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Failed");
        } //End catch
        try
        {
        stmt.executeUpdate(insertStatement);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }
        try
        {
        stmt.executeUpdate(insertStatementTwo);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }
        try
        {
        stmt.executeUpdate(insertStatementThree);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
        try
        {
        stmt.executeUpdate(insertStatementFour);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }
        try
        {
        stmt.executeUpdate(insertStatementFive);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }
        try
        {
        stmt.executeUpdate(insertStatementSix);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
        }
        conn.close();
    } //End try
    catch(SQLException ex)
    {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    } //End catch
}
```

Comment: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException:java.net.ConnectException:Error Connecting to server localhost on = port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect. your connection was refused. so either your computer can't find the host computer, your credentials may be wrong (username/password) or the port number may be wrong, or the file path may be wrong

Comment: Duplicate of [Java establish connection to jdbc with code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25993151/java-establish-connection-to-jdbc-with-code)

Comment: Do not repost your questions.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely thing is change your connection url.

Replace

```
String createDB = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/C:/21109220/HotelBookings;create=true";
```

with

```
String createDB = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/HotelBookings;create=true";
```

or

```
String createDB = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/HotelBookings";
```

Then it should be ok.